# For loop in python keeps cycling

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, for-loop

Disclaimer: total beginner.
This is the code snippet I'm having problems with.

```
list = []
table = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('tbody')
tr = table.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')

for i in tr:
    if i.find_elements_by_xpath("""//a[contains(@href, 'thing1')]"""):
        name = i.find_elements_by_xpath("""//a[contains(@href, 'thing1')]""")[1]
        text = name.text
        list.append(text)

    if i.find_elements_by_xpath("""//a[contains(@href, 'thing2')]"""):
        link = i.find_element_by_xpath("""//a[contains(@href, 'thing2')]""")
        link_text = link.text
        list.append(link_text)
        address = link.get_attribute('href')
        list.append(address)
```

The html looks something like this:

```
<tbody>
   <tr>
      <a>Hit on if statement 1. Ignore.</a>
      <a>Hit on if statement 1. Always one of these tr elements.</a>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <a>Hit on if statement 2. Tr like this could repeat n times.</a> 
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

This pattern within tbody could be repeated n times.

The first iteration of the loop works perfectly, but after that it just keeps repeating that same first iteration forever. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: "The first iteration of the loop works perfectly, but after that it just keeps repeating that same first iteration forever" - can you explain why you think that this is what's happening?

Comment: If I knew I wouldn't be posting this...

Comment: I'm asking you how you came to the conclusion you've asserted; I'm not asking what's causing the bug.

Comment: Print in the if statements for text, link text and address.

Comment: Print `i` immediately within the for-loop and verify that you get what you expect

Comment: @user686368 Be honest, is this the exact code you used or did you dumb it down for posting here?

Comment: Exact code just different variable names. The print statement for i gives me <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="always same numbers", element="always same numbers-[[[This number goes up by one each time, starting from 1.]]]")>

Comment: is this the exact html code? I dont see any href on your a tags. Its easy to figure out the issue if you can provide the exact html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out what I did wrong. All the xpath statements need a dot:

```
find_elements_by_xpath(""".//a[contains(@href, 'thing1')]""")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using eTree like example below. . .  .where filepath should be your path of xml file

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(filepath)
    for tab_row in tree.iter(tag='tr'):
        print(tab_row.text)enter code here
```